# Atribute erro in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I have an attribution problem. In this case, I'm using the Kivy library and when I use the command `variable().Run()` to run the screen, the following error appears: `object has no attribute to 'run'`. How can I resolve this?

I've tried

[image]

changing the variable name and trying to define another function to use with the `.run()` command, but to no avail.

Comment: First, don't store your custom Python scripts inside the `venv` folder - it's your virtual environment. Store them in the project root instead. Second, you create an empty class `ap` and call the undefined `run()` method. `AttributeError` is expected as it doesn't make sense. I suggest following some Kivy tutorials closely to start with.